# Find the limit distribution of $Y_{n}=\bar{X}_{n}+1$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $\bar{X}_{n}$ denote the mean of a random sample of size $n$ from a distribution that has pdf

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}2 x, & 0<x<1 \\ 0, & \text { otherwise }\end{array}\right.$

Find the limit distribution of $Y_{n}=\bar{X}_{n}+1$.

---

I have try to use moment generating function.

$M_{Y_n}(t)=E(e^{tY_n})=e^t[M_x(\frac{t}{n})]^n$

Since: $$M_X(t)=E(e^{tx})=\int_0^12xe^{tx}dx$$
$$M_X(t)=\frac{2}{t}$$
$$M_X(\frac{t}{n})=\frac{2n}{t}$$
$$M_{Y_n}(t)=e^t\left(\frac{2n}{t}\right)^n$$
At this, I have stuck on this. Please give me some hints on this. Thank in advanced!

Comment: Your computation of the integral in $M_X(t)$ is not correct. Also, the law of large numbers implies $\bar{X}_n \to 2/3$, so you don't need to use MGFs.

Answer (score 1):

Your $M_X$ is wrong: one has
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \int_{0}^{1}2xe^{tx}\text{ d}x = 2\int_{0}^{1}xe^{tx}\text{ d}x\text{.}$$
Integrate by parts by setting $u = x$, $\text{d}v = e^{tx}\text{ d}x$ - then we have $\text{d}u = \text{d}x$ and $v = \dfrac{1}{t}e^{tx}$. Hence
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = 2\left(\left. x\dfrac{1}{t}e^{tx} \right|^{x=1}_{x=0}-\dfrac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{1}e^{tx}\text{ d}x \right) = 2\left[\dfrac{e^t}{t} - \dfrac{1}{t^2}(e^t - 1)\right]\text{.}$$

Comment: Could you show me how to calculate limit distribution using MGF?